# AngularJS: Unable to access a service method

Tags: angularjs

I am just learning how to use services to slim down my controllers.

I created a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/00O25I43Td61Ls8EyctG?p=preview) and I am returning this error: Error -- TypeError: undefined is not a function pointing to this line ".then(function(crops){"

Here is my index.html (pretty simple)

```
<body ng-controller="MainController">
    <pre>{{selectedCrops | json}}</pre>
</body>
```

and here is script.js

```
(function(){
  angular.module('app',[]);

  angular.module('app')
    .service('LoanSvc', function($http, $q){
      this.getSelectedCrops = function(){
        return {
          show_corn: true,
          show_beans: true,
          show_sorghum: true,
          show_wheat: true,
          show_cotton: true,
          show_rice: true,
          show_peanuts: true,
          show_sugarcane: true
        };
      }
    });

  angular.module('app').controller('MainController', function($scope, LoanSvc){
    LoanSvc.getSelectedCrops()
      .then(function(crops){
        $scope.selectedCrops = crops;
      })
  });
}());
```

Any guidance is coveted!

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your service doesn't make any HTTP queries and just returns an object with data, you do not need to use the `.then()` with the return value for `LoanSvc.getSelectedCrops()`.

Instead, you can just use the value directly in your controller:

```
$scope.selectedCrops = LoanSvc.getSelectedCrops();
```

Eventually, you will probably want to modify your service to get the data from the server. This is why you inject `$http` into the service. So you might modify your `LoanSvc.getSelectedCrops()` function to use `$http.get()` which returns a `$promise`. When you do that, you will be able to use the `then()` function to handle the asynchronous response from the server.

You might modify your service something like this to query a server:

```
angular.module('app')
    .service('LoanSvc', function($http, $q){
      this.getSelectedCrops = function(){
          return $http.get('some_url/get_crops');
});
```